# NSIS: environment variable created doesn't work

Tags: nsis

I am creating a Env Variable and then appending it to the PATH variable in my NSIS installer script on Win7 - 64 bit.

```
Push "MyPath"
Push "D:\MyFolder\bin;D:\MyFolder\lib"
Call WriteEnvStr

Push "%MyPath%"
Call AddToPath
```

Now after installation I can see both the variable in cmd prompt

```
MyPath=D:\MyFolder\bin;D:\MyFolder\lib
Path=%MyPath%;<my existsing path>
```

But any exe/dll from  are not found at run time.
If I run the cmd prompt as Administrator and then run exe, it runs fine.
It also works if I run exe directly as an Administrator.

Also interesting is that if I open Environment editor, double click on MyPath variable and click OK (without changing anything), my exe's run fine without running as Administrator.
And now if I check Path in cmd prompt, MyPath variable is substituted

```
MyPath=D:\MyFolder\bin;D:\MyFolder\lib
Path=D:\MyFolder\bin;D:\MyFolder\lib;<my existsing path>
```

I tried to add "Call EnvVarUpdate" after creating the env variable but it doesn't work.

I am using NSIS Unicode version 2.46.3

Comment: I have seen answers in SuperUser which suggest that it is not an NSIS issue, but Windows which has problems with env. variable within another env. variable. Not sure how true it is.

Answer (score 0):

Your chances of adding/modifying the path without losing data in path by truncating it would be much greater by using the registry.

```
ReadRegStr $0 HKCU "Environment" Path
StrCpy $1 "D:\MyFolder\bin;D:\MyFolder\lib"
StrCpy $2 "$0;$1"
WriteRegStr HKCU "Environment" Path "$2"
```

If your system has an AUTOEXEC.BAT file then any PATH setting in AUTOEXEC.BAT will also be appended to the %PATH% environment variable. This is to provide compatibility with old installation routines which need to set the PATH. All other commands in AUTOEXEC.BAT are ignored however. And this is more or less obsolete anyway.

But we could just continue with your method however just try a different means of acomplishing your goal. I have not tested this but you can try something similar to this:

```
StrCpy $R0 "MYPATH"
StrCpy $R1 "D:\MyFolder\bin;D:\MyFolder\lib"
System::Call `Kernel32::SetEnvironmentVariable(t"$R0",t"$R1")`
```

Now include your new variable in the path like the following:

```
ReadEnvStr $R0 COMSPEC
ReadEnvStr $R1 MYPATH
ExecDos::Exec /TOSTACK `"$R0" /c "SetX PATH=%PATH%;$R1 -m"`
```

You can now easily change that one variable %MYPATH% at any time in the future and the PATH will reflect the new value.

Answer (score -2):

```
 ${EnvVarUpdate} $0 "PATH" "A" "HKLM" "C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin"

 StrCpy $R0 "$0"

 System::Call 'Kernel32::SetEnvironmentVariableA(t, t) i("PATH", R0).r2'

 ReadEnvStr $R0 "PATH"

 ExecWait "$INSTDIR\tmp\batchfile.bat
```